# Download a CSV file then upload to MySQL using Python

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, csv

I have tried to build out simple python script to collect "live" earthquake data
from the USGS site which is delivered in an CSV file.  My desire it to grab the
data using python the have it turn around and update the MySQL server I have
built.

```
C:\Python27\python.exe C:/Users/XXXX/PycharmProjects/QuakeUpload/TestSQLOpen2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/XXXX/PycharmProjects/QuakeUpload/TestSQLOpen2.py", line 19, in <module>
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 745, in cursor
    return self.cursorclass(self)
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Process finished with exit code 1
```

---

```
import pymysql
import codecs
import csv
import urllib2
import pymysql.cursors

# Get URL Data
url = "http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/all_month.csv"
URLstream = urllib2.urlopen(url)
csvfile = csv.reader(codecs.iterdecode(URLstream, 'utf-8'))
# for rows in csvfile:
#    print(rows)

# Connect to the database

connection = pymysql.connect(host='b8con.no-ip.org', user='sal', password='XXXXXX', db='EarthQuake', charset='utf8mb4', cursorclass="pymysql.cursors.DictCursor")

try:
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        sql = "INSERT INTO quakedata(time, latitude, longitude, depth, mag, magType, nst, gap, dmin, rms, net, id, updated, place, type) VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
        next(csvfile, None)
        for line in csvfile():
            cursor.execute(sql, (line[0], line[1], line[2], line[3], line[4], line[5], line[6], line[7], line[8], line[9], line[10], line[11], line[12], line[13], line[14]))

finally:
    connection.close()



'''
next(csvfile, None)
for line in csvfile:
    print(line[0], line[1], line[2], line[3], line[4], line[5], line[6], line[7], line[8], line[9], line[10], line[11], line[12], line[13], line[14])
    sql = "INSERT INTO quakedata(time, latitude, longitude, depth, mag, magType, nst, gap, dmin, rms, net, id, updated, place, type) VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
    cursor.execute(sql, (line[0], line[1], line[2], line[3], line[4], line[5], line[6], line[7], line[8], line[9], line[10], line[11], line[12], line[13], line[14]))


connection.commit()


connection.close()
'''
```

Comment: There are an extra parentheses in `for line in csvfile():`

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, the traceback error message does not show the line which causes the error. The line that causes the error occurs before the call to `connection.cursor()` (the line the traceback targets as the source of the problem).

The error is caused by

```
connection = pymysql.connect(host='b8con.no-ip.org', user='sal', 
                 password='bigsal71', db='EarthQuake', charset='utf8mb4', 
                 cursorclass="pymysql.cursors.DictCursor")
```

which can be fixed by 
[removing the double quotes from around the cursorclass](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL#example):

```
connection = pymysql.connect(..., cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
```

Note that `pymysql.cursors.DictCursor` is a
class while `"pymysql.cursors.DictCursor"` is a string.  If `self.cursorclass` is
set to `pymysql.cursors.DictCursor` (via the `cursorclass` argument), then the line

```
return self.cursorclass(self)
```

returns an instance of the `DictCursor` class. If instead `self.cursorclass` is the string `"pymysql.cursors.DictCursor"`, then calling the string raises

```
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

since strings are not callable.

---

Also, as [nightuser points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32107136/download-a-csv-file-then-upload-to-mysql-using-python/32107365#comment52108803_32107136),

```
for line in csvfile():
```

should be

```
for line in csvfile:
```

(without the parentheses) since `csvfile` itself is the iterable.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys! I was able to get it to work. Here is what my final code looks like.

```
import pymysql
import codecs
import csv
import urllib2
import pymysql.cursors

# Get URL Data
url = "http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/all_month.csv"
URLstream = urllib2.urlopen(url)
csvfile = csv.reader(codecs.iterdecode(URLstream, 'utf-8'))

# Connect to the database

connection = pymysql.connect(host='b8con.no-ip.org', user='HanSolo', password='password', db='EarthQuake', charset='utf8mb4', cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)

try:
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        sql = "INSERT INTO quakedata(time, latitude, longitude, depth, mag, magType, nst, gap, dmin, rms, net, id, updated, place, type) VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
        next(csvfile, None)
        for line in csvfile:
            cursor.execute(sql, (line[0], line[1], line[2], line[3], line[4], line[5], line[6], line[7], line[8], line[9], line[10], line[11], line[12], line[13], line[14]))

finally:
    connection.commit()
    connection.close()
```